# std::vector autocomplete not working inside Xcode 6.6

Tags: c++, xcode, std, stdvector

I'm just trying to build a very simple program that uses std::vector in Xcode.
Here are my configuration settings -

- Apple LLVM 6.1 - Language C++ C++ Language dialect =
- GNU++11[-std=gnu++11] C++ Standard Library = libc++ (LLVM C++
  standard library with C++11 support)

Code like this below works fine, I can use the std:: library as I need it. However, the ctrl+space autocomplete doesn't seem to work for some things. Like for example, it doesn't give me std::vector as an suggestion

```
std::vector<double> measurements
```

Here are my header search paths

-/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include

-/usr/local/include

What could I be doing wrong? The code builds and runs fine!